# Simulate an open web socket with nock

Tags: node.js, websocket, mocking, nock

I am trying to use nock to run backtests on code written against Oanda's trading API.  To do that, I need to simulate the streaming price API (see Rates Streaming at http://developer.oanda.com/rest-practice/streaming/).  However, it seems like nock only lets you respond with a single reply, even though the response is a stream.  Is there any way to send a stream of thousands of price events as individual responses to a single request?

```
var scopeStream = nock('https://stream-fxpractice.oanda.com')
  .persist()
  .filteringPath(function(path) {
    return '/stream';
  })
  .get('/stream')
  .reply(function(uri, requestBody) {
    return [200, {"tick":{"instrument":"AUD_CAD","time":"2014-01-30T20:47:08.066398Z","bid":0.98114,"ask":0.98139}}]
  })
```

Comment: Crickets :-(  No ideas?

Comment: Note that nock is about "HTTP server mocking" and the WebSocket protocol is not HTTP. Probably you mean [Server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) rather than WebSockets.

Answer (score 4):

According to this [Nock documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock#specifying-replies) you can return a ReadStream in your reply.

I used the [stream-spigot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-spigot) npm package to come up with the following example (used to simulate a Marathon event stream):

```
const nock = require('nock');

const EventSource = require('eventsource');
const spigot = require('stream-spigot');

let i = 0;

nock('http://marathon.com')
      .get('/events')
      .reply(200, (uri, req) => {
          // reply with a stream
          return spigot({objectMode: true}, function() {
              const self = this;
              if (++i < 5)
                  setTimeout(() => this.push(`id: ${i}\ndata: foo\n\n`), 1000);
          })
      });

const es = new EventSource('http://marathon.com/events');

es.onmessage = m => console.log(m);

es.onerror = e => console.log(e);
```